# problem with .attr() method for getting value of attributes of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a string like this :

```
string_data = "<option value='1'>ahmad</option><option value='2'>mohammad</option><option value='3'>ali</option>"
```

now i want get the value of value attribute of options and alert it. for this i write this :

```
$(string_data).contents()
.each(function(){
    value   =   $(this).attr('value');
    text    =   $(this).text();
    alert(value);
});
```

but this code return **undefined** for all of them .
in Addition **string_data** is a string that i get it from a php script with Ajax via $.post() jQuery method.
i am using jquery 1.6 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contents()` method retrieves the **children** of your elements which in your case are the text nodes. Omit that method call to iterate through `<option>` elements:

```
$(string_data).each(function(){
    value   =   $(this).attr('value');
    text    =   $(this).text();
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(string_data).find("option")
.each(function(){
    value   =   $(this).attr('value');
    text    =   $(this).text();
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's valid to load the string_data like this, when jQuery expects an identifier. It should probably be more like:

```
$('#some_hidden_select').html(string_data).find("option")
.each(function(){
    value   =   $(this).attr('value');
    text    =   $(this).text();
    alert(value);
});
```